# Syncfusion cutom widget onchanged parameter doesnot take void Function onPressed

Tags: flutter, slider, syncfusion

I am trying to create a custom vertical slider with 4 in a row and I am using Syncfusion package, however, when I create a customer widget, onchanged parameter does not accept the Function variable when passed.

```dart
SfSliderTheme(
  data: SfSliderThemeData(
    thumbColor: Colors.blue[200],
    activeTrackHeight: kactive_slider_height,
    inactiveTrackHeight: kinactive_slider_height,
    activeTrackColor: kactive_slider_track_color,
    inactiveTrackColor: Colors.black,
    trackCornerRadius: -1.0,
  ),
  child: SfSlider.vertical(
    min: 0.0,
    max: 100.0,
    value: value,
    onChanged: (value) {},
  ),
),
```

This is my code and I am using multiple times, I want to create a custom widget but onChanged: does not take void Function onPressed. Is there a way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While interacting with the slider, we will get the new value in the onChanged method. So that we can update the slider thumb with the new value. The new value is the type of dynamic, because the slider supports numeric and date time types.

```
double value = 50.0;
SfSlider.vertical(
    min: 0.0,
    max: 100.0,
    value: value,
    onChanged: (dynamic newValue) {
        setState(() {
           value = newValue;
        });
   },
)
```

Comment: hi there :) seems you're new to the site. just so you're aware, you don't have to frame answers as you would frame a support email - it'd be enough to explain the solution to the problem, as you've done under your greeting with your short explanation and the code paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `SfSlider.vertical` does take in a `ValueChanged` function but I think you're seeing an error because there is not enough type information?  Based on the documentation it looks like there is no generic associated with `SfSlider` so the callback you should use would use `dynamic` e.g `(dynamic value) { ... }`

```dart
  child: SfSlider.vertical(
    min: 0.0,
    max: 100.0,
    value: value,
    onChanged: (dynamic value) {},
  ),
```